# What is the meaning of this order in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

For example, the code is shown as follows,

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-10,20,0.2)

y = 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-x))

fig, [ax0, ax1] = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(8,4)) 

...

...
```

What is the meaning of this sentence mean:

```
fig, [ax0, ax1] = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(8,4))
```

I understand the right hand means plotting subplots and the number of columns is 2 and size of the figure is defined, but I do not understand what does the left hand side mean?

```
fig, [ax0, ax1]
```

I think the meaning of it is not defining a function or a variable, so I want to know the meaning of it.

Comment: it's unpacking, knowing that the function returns a tuple of an object and another tuple/list containing 2 elements.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre to be utterly pedantic, it returns an *iterable* with exactly two elements, the second element being itself an iterable with exactly two elements... ;)

Comment: you're absolutely right. I just felt I had to comment before searching & closing as duplicate. The original question is sooo detailed it's difficult to do better :)